# Filling a doubly linked list for bi-directional traversal

Tags: c++, linked-list

Good evening, everyone, I have another question. As always, if this is a duplicate, point me to the thread I'm duplicating (if I could find it, I wouldn't be posting). I was going through and updating some ancient code on my github, and rewriting it to be **less** moronic, and wound up with a question of both theory and implementation. In a doubly linked list (where head and tail need to be kept track of), how should the first member be initialized? Pushing from the front leaves an uninitialized (or improperly initialized) tail, and vice versa.

Here's what I mean

```
template <typename T>
void double_list<T>::push_back(T data)
{
    if(tail)
    {
        node<T>* temp = new node<T>;
        temp->data = data;

        this->tail->next = temp;
        temp->prev = this->tail;
        this->tail = temp;
    }
    else
    {
        if(!head) //New list
        {
            this->head = new node<T>;
            this->tail = new node<T>;

            this->tail->data = data;

            this->tail->prev = this->head;
            this->head->next = this->tail;
        }
    }
}
template <typename T>
void double_list<T>::pop_back(T* out)
{
    if(this->tail->prev)
    {

            *out = this->tail->data;

            this->tail = this->tail->prev;
            this->tail->next = NULL;

            //numel -= 1;

    }
    else
        throw pop_empty();
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "list.h"
#include "list_inst.h"


using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double_list<int> myList1;
    double_list<int> myList2;
    double_list<int> myList3;
    double_list<int> myList4;

    bool finished = false;

    for(int i = 1; i <= 25; i++)
    {
        myList1.push_front(i);
        myList2.push_front(i);
        myList3.push_back(i);
        myList4.push_back(i);
    }

    cout << "First list (25 - 1) forward traversal:\n";
    while(!finished)
    {
        try
        {
            int val = 0;
            myList1.pop_front(&val);
            cout << val << ", ";
        }
        catch(pop_empty &bad_pop)
        {
            finished = true;
        }
    }
    cout << "\n\n";
    finished = false;

    cout << "Second list (25 - 1) reverse traversal:\n";
    while(!finished)
    {
        try
        {
            int val = 0;
            myList2.pop_back(&val);
            cout << val << ", ";
        }
        catch(pop_empty &bad_pop)
        {
            finished = true;
        }
    }
    cout << "\n\n";
    finished = false;

    cout << "Third list (1 - 25) forward traversal:\n";
    while(!finished)
    {
        try
        {
            int val = 0;
            myList3.pop_front(&val);
            cout << val << ", ";
        }
        catch(pop_empty &bad_pop)
        {
            finished = true;
        }
    }
    cout << "\n\n";
    finished = false;

    cout << "Fourth list(1 - 25) reverse traversal:\n";
    while(!finished)
    {
        try
        {
            int val = 0;
            myList4.pop_back(&val);
            cout << val << ", ";
        }
        catch(pop_empty &bad_pop)
        {
            finished = true;
        }
    }
    cout << "\n\n";
    finished = false;

    return 0;
}
```

When the traversal styles match (front with front, back with back), no problem, but I want to allow this a bit more flexibility, and frankly, learn something my professors never bothered to mention when I was in school. Any criticism is also welcome, as I only post here to learn. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If your goal is to improve this code, scrap it and use `std::list`. If your goal to learn about doubly linked list implementations, read your `std::list` implementation.

Comment: With all due respect, I'm well aware of each and every one of the STL data types, this is an exercise for my own benefit, as well as friends I help to tutor going through data structures. As for reading implementations, I did that when I was debugging SDL gamepad input. It's faster to just ask for help for me. Again, I mean this with respect, I can see how it comes out as bitchy, but I'm just trying to be explanatory.

Comment: It's very much OK to implement a doubly linked list for education, nothing wrong with that. Somebody has to write this std:: implementation in the end. Answers you will get here don't replace learning on your own.  They will answer your focused question, but they may or may not teach you the best technique, like using a sentinel node (which is to my knowledge is a technique used in all existing std implementations).

Comment: Thank you for that. All I'm trying to do with these is learn a bit more theory, and practice what I do know, and a narrow answer is all I ever want, or ask for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need an extra node for head and tail. If the list consists of one element head an tail point to the same element.

```
template <typename T>
void double_list<T>::push_back(T data)
{
    if ( tail != nullptr )
    {
        node<T>* temp = new node<T>;
        temp->data = data;

        this->tail->next = temp;
        temp->prev = this->tail;
        this->tail = temp;
    }
    else
    {
        this->tail = this->head = new node<T>;
        this->tail->prev = this->head->next = nullptr;
        this->tail->data = data;
    }
}

template <typename T>
void double_list<T>::pop_back(T* out)
{
    if ( this->tail != nullptr )
    {
        node<T>* temp = this->tail;
        *out = this->tail->data;
        if ( this->tail->prev != nullptr )
        {
            this->tail = this->tail->prev;
            this->tail->next = NULL;
        }
        else
            this->tail = this->head = nullptr;
        delete temp;
    }
    else
        throw pop_empty();
}
```

Referring to the comment of n.m. the solution for c++ is `std::list`.

Comment: You forgot to delete the node.

Comment: Hm. It will be interesting to define an efficient iterator-interface for that list.